# Cloudformation conditional templateURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to do conditional template urls in cloudformation?

This fails because it is not evaluated until the `aws cloudformation deploy` step and it errors out saying that the templateURL must be an s3 link. When I hard code in one of the urls it will upload that relative file to s3 and in the packaged final template it will just have the s3 url in place.

**This doesn't work (pre aws cloudformation package step)**

```yaml
   Vpc:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertingModule: !GetAtt 'Alerting.Outputs.StackName'
        NatGateways: 'true'
      TemplateURL: !If [IsProduction, './default-vpc-module.yml', './production-vpc-module.yml']
```

**When a url is hardcoded in it will package into this (post aws cloudformation pacakge step)**

```yaml
    VpcModule:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - Vpc
          - Outputs.StackName
        AlertingModule:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - Alerting
          - Outputs.StackName
        Priority: '2'
        HealthCheckPath: /health-check.php
      TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-cicd-bucket-/fe556ff9386a28c063c4a110b31b.template
```

Comment: In your first version, the urls are not s3 links. In docs it [writes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-templateurl): "The URL **must** point to a template (max size: 460,800 bytes) that is located in an Amazon S3 bucket.". The second version is proper s3 link.

Comment: I added more context.
the first snippet is before the aws cloudformation package step
the second is a snippet after the aws cloudformation package step WHEN the relative urls are hardcoded (not in an if statement)

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work". This is how I'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you absolutely can achieve what your after, the way i did it was reference the s3 url, by using an aws cloudformaiton package but also a s3 cp in the codebuild stage to enforce naming conventions on the url. As long as your template url paths are distinguished differently.

To provide a very flexible example, you could use !Sub with an !If replacement statement on the dynamic name component, which will also allow your to use !Ref inside the !If statement:

```
Parameters:
  StageProd:
    Description: Environment
    Default: "production"
    Type: String
.......
```

---

```
......
    TemplateURL: !Sub 
        - https://${CfnBucketName}.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/${CfnKeyPrefix}/SomeFileName-${Stage}.yaml
        - { Stage: !If [ IsProduction, !Ref StageProd, "default"]}
```

The above should meet almost any sort of combination of dynamic naming you want to achieve; however, you could also very much simplify the above with a simple !Sub replacing the stage name.

Comment: I tried that out, but unfortunately that didn´t work for me

Comment: Which part didn't work? @EllisTheEllice

Comment: CloudFormation tells me: TemplateURL must be a supported URL.
When I hardcode the string, it works.

Comment: Tricky to debug unless you post your reference. But are you including the https text at the start ? If your hardcode string works I'd suspect it's the way your referencing could be the issue?

Comment: I had a similar problem, @EllisTheEllice.
I was using this syntax and got the same Error:                    
TemplateURL: !Sub https://{BucketNameVariable}.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/path_to_template/template.yml

But changing the path format and adding double quotes did the trick:                      
TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/${BucketNameVariable}/path_to_template/template.yml"

You can find some other path formats here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/best-practices-for-using-amazon-s3-endpoints-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing, but I don't like it.

```yaml
  Vpc:
    Condition: IsProduction
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertingModule: !GetAtt 'Alerting.Outputs.StackName'
        NatGateways: 'true' # reduce costs
      TemplateURL: ./production-vpc-module.yml
  Vpc:
    Condition: IsNotProduction
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        AlertingModule: !GetAtt 'Alerting.Outputs.StackName'
        NatGateways: 'true' # reduce costs
      TemplateURL: ./default-vpc-module.yml
```